# How can I filter an IList<Models.HomeMenuOverview> HomeMenuOverviews { get; set; }

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, filtering

The model contains the User Id and I have the the User Id (WorkColUserId) in the session Id (SessionIdId) so I could filter the IList or I could generate an already reduced IList in order to reduce me home menu depending on rights. Tks for your Help.

==== Here is my model ====

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Models
{
    public class HomeMenuOverview
    {
        [Key]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public string MenuText { get; set; }
        public string AssignedFunction { get; set; }
        public bool PermissionIndex { get; set; }
        public bool PermissionCreate { get; set; }
        public bool PermissionEdit { get; set; }
        public bool PermissionDetail { get; set; }
        public bool PermissionDelete { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int WorkColUserId { get; set; }
        public string WorkColUserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

==== Here is my C# code =====

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WorkCollaboration.Models;

namespace WorkCollaboration.Pages
{

    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext _context;

        public IndexModel(WorkCollaboration.Data.WorkCollaborationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Models.HomeMenuOverview> HomeMenuOverviews { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {

            string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
            string SessionKeyId = "_Id";
            string SessionKeyDate = "_Date";

            var SessionIdDate = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyDate);
            var SessionIdId = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyId);
            var SessionIdName = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);


            HomeMenuOverviews = await _context.HomeMenuOverview.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

==== Here is my page =====

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using System.Web
@using WorkCollaboration.Models
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3 class="display-4">Welcome</h3>
    </div>
    <h1>Menu</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.HomeMenuOverviews)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page=@item.AssignedFunction>@item.MenuText</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

===== Here the picture of the application with unfiltered data =====

!Picture of menu [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR4BW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter HomeMenuOverview with SessionIdId,you can do like this:

```
HomeMenuOverviews = await _context.HomeMenuOverview.Where(h => h.WorkColUserId == SessionIdId).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Great learning for me.